# SQL Server Graph database

Tags: sql-server, graph, sql-graph

I would like to know if a graph database can be added to an AOAG. I know it can't use replication, but was wondering if it was supported in AOAG's.

Answer (score 0):

There are no restrictions on using [SQL Server Graph Database Capabilities](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/graphs/sql-graph-overview) in a database that participates in an AlwaysOn Availability Group. AG replicates the physical database files between instances, so is broadly compatible database engine features.

If there were any they would be documented here:  [Prerequisites, Restrictions, and Recommendations for Always On availability groups](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/availability-groups/windows/prereqs-restrictions-recommendations-always-on-availability?view=sql-server-ver15)